# I keep geting this error: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting ')' on line 8

Tags: php

I can't workout where to put the bracket/s any help would be great, Thanks.

```
<?php 
defined('APPLICATION_PATH') || define('APPLICATION_PATH',realpath(dirname(__FILE__) . '/../app'));
const DS = DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
require APPLICATION_PATH . DS .'config' . DS . 'config.php';


$page = get (name:'page', def: 'home');

$model = $config['MODEL_PATH'] . $page . '.php';
$view  = $config['VIEW'] . $page . '.phtml';
$_404  = $config['VIEW'] . $page . '.phtml';

if(file_exists($model))
{
    require $model;
}
```

Comment: Try `$page = get('page', 'home');`

Comment: [Named arguments](https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.named-arguments) are only available in PHP 8